# Cakephp Shell can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to get a crontab working for Cakephp (running on my shared Dreamhost server for now).

I have a shell set up as per the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html), which works fine via either a cron run or manually executing (both via a shell file, e.g:

```
cron.sh
#########
cd /pathToApp/app/Console
/usr/local/bin/php cake.php updater list_reports
```

where updater is my shell and list_reports a method thereof.

The problem occurs when I try to access the database in the shell ("Using models in your shell", same link).

Error Message:

> Error: Database connection "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to
>   local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"
>   is missing, or could not be created.

My DB Set-up (site works fine for http, do I need to add `unix_socket` or something?

```
array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'mysql.mydomain.net',
        'port' => '3306',
        'login' => '*******',
        'password' => '*******',
        'database' => '*******',
        'prefix' => '',
    );
```

Thing I've tried:

- Creating a symlink to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` - permission denied
- Can I even do this with shared hosting?
- Tried various changes to the db settings above, no luck.
- I note similar problems have been solved by people replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, but I'm using a shared host, not local.

Comment: From the error message it sounds like it's trying to connect to a local mysql database, instead of your remote database.

Comment: Good spot, I'd been concentrating on the socket bit of the err msg, hadn't noticed the implication of the word "local". It's shared hosting, with mysql.mydomain.net being a hostname set via the Dreamhost panel - is this relevant?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dreamhost, but can you try executing your script like:
cd /pathToApp/app
Console/cake updater list_reports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's official! I'm a db!

I can confirm this problem was not caused by either Cakephp or Mysql, but rather for something I'd done myself and forgot about....

I had a little switch in database.php to automatically detect whether I was in the dev, test, staging environment etc. I had the default set to local, and since the bash script didn't pick up $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] which I was using for the switch, it defaulted to my local db.

Thanks to ifunk for spotting the clue which enabled me to unravel this and get back on track!

:)

Comment: that is the reason why I also append the path of the app - so the switch also works for CLI on all environments - see http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/25/dynamic-database-switching/

Comment: Good info mark - never seen the environment or path keys in docs.. are they uniquely used by your setup plugin?

Comment: i invented them :) so they are unique to my plugin/setupclass